# What is the land only value of my property

Tags: united-kingdom, land

I'm looking to find the value of the **land only**, for my house in the UK. Is there a way to find this out?

I have the cost to rebuild, and the current property value, is it as simple as subtracting the two?

I'm a UK citizen, with property in the UK, requiring the information for my USA taxes.

Comment: It's rather a theoretical question - do you want the value of the land with nothing on it? Because to get there from having a house on it would actually cost money (demolishing the house), so a lot depends on the specific scenario you are interested in.

Comment: I need land value for tax reasons

Comment: Doesn't your local tax authority provide the rule that they use for this calculation then? Whether not that's a "good" valuation by whatever other metric you want to define, it seems like it would be authoritative for the scenario that you currently have.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but where would I find that information? I'm in Sefton Merseyside if that matters?

Comment: Maybe by getting your tax band? https://www.gov.uk/council-tax-bands.  The terminology on the UK sites is not familiar to me, but a quick search suggests this might do it.  You might back it out if you know your tax rate from here: https://www.sefton.gov.uk/council-tax/council-tax-bands-and-charges.aspx under "How your tax is worked out"

Comment: @Brick: those are based on total property values, not land value specifically.

Comment: Tax reasons in what country? I don't think the UK typically taxes based on land value.

Comment: USA has some things around land vs property value

Answer (score 4):

Land value isn't really a concept most people think about in the UK, so it will be difficult to get an accurate value.

Your proposal of `(property value - rebuild cost)` seems like the best option, and will probably be good enough for US tax purposes. Getting an accurate rebuild value may be hard as ideally you would ask a surveyor for a precise estimate, which itself would cost money. For a rough value you can use [this online calculator](http://abi.bcis.co.uk/).

You can also get a very rough idea of land values by searching for land for sale, but there isn't all that much of it that would help with the value of a single plot: most property development happens on larger scale sites.

[This site](http://www.uklanddirectory.org.uk/) does have a few listings for Merseyside which might help, but obviously land values could vary a great deal by locality within a single area. You should be looking at plots with "Detailed planning permission" for "Residential development", as your own land would fall under the category. However there are only a very few plots listed, and there might well be circumstances specific to those plots that make them atypical.

Comment: Agree that total value - cost of rebuild is a good approximation. As to looking at sales, my feeling would be that (sub)urban plots for sale are uncommon enough that the pricing would be skewed by other factors specific to those plots - & most probably have a specific reason as to why they're vacant!

Comment: @Andrew: good point. I've tweaked my answer.